# Trace OpenGL calls doesn't work

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-device-monitor

I am analyzing the GPU performance on Android. I know the 'trace opengl calls' tools in Android device monitor.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/gltracer.html

However, when I click trace here,
[image]

nothing happens.

Can anybody tell me what I have to do to get those traces?

more details,

Android Device Monitor
Version: 25.2.2

Android Studio
Version: 2.3.3